# What's '2>&1' and '/dev/null'

Tags: dev

I have been browsing through scripts and see `2>&1` & `/dev/null` everywhere. What are they? After googling, is it different for OS X than for Linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three 'standard file streams' that Unix processes may make use of - `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` - `stdin` usually reads input from the keyboard, and `stdout` and `stderr` usually go to your terminal window. `stderr` gets file descriptor number `2`, and stdout gets file descriptor number `1`. `2>&1` means "redirect all output to stderr to the same place that stdout is going". `/dev/null` is a character device - it simply discards anything written to it.

If you don't want to store the output of a script anywhere, and you don't want to see it on your terminal, you may redirect `stderr` to the same place as `stdout` with `2>&1`, and then redirect `stdout` to `/dev/null` with `> /dev/null`

If you only were to redirect `stdout` with `> /dev/null`, you would still see errors on your terminal.

Answer (score 1):

`2>&1` is the information for the shell  executing the script to redirect all the output including errors to specified destination like file or `/dev/null`

The `/dev` location in Linux systems provides the system with access to devices. One of those devices is a pseudo-device called null. /dev/null is an empty device - a vacuum if you will. It does nothing besides being a hole where you put something and it disapears. If you copy `/dev/null` to some file like:

```
cp /dev/null /tmp/foo
```

the specified file will be empty.

Detailed information about redirecting output you can be found [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html).

And [here](http://linux.about.com/cs/linux101/g/slshdevslshnull.htm) is a full definition of /dev/null:

> On UNIX, this is a virtual-file that can be written to. Data written
>   to this file gets discarded. It is similar to the file call NUL on
>   Windows machines. Key point: When rooting a machine, intruders will
>   often redirect logging to /dev/null For example, the command ln -s
>   /dev/null .bash_history will cause the system to stop logging bash
>   commands. Culture: In the vernacular, means much the same thing as
>   black hole. Typical usage: if you don't like what I have to say,
>   please direct your comments to /dev/null.

Comment: Please don't give examples using important system files such as grub.cfg. Deleting that file will render your system unbootable.

Comment: I tried the grub.cfg thing and as soon as I entered the command, my computer shut down, the motherboard started playing pop goes the weasel and my LCD screen burst into flames displaying 0xdeadbeef in letters of fire. Don't try it.